# Using a Dell UltraSharp 27 4K USB-C Monitor: U2720Q display as a monitor for IPad-Air 4th Gen

Tags: display, ipad

I have an IPad-Air 4th Gen which has USB-C port.
I recently bought a "Dell UltraHD 4K USB-C Monitor: U2720Q" which also has USB-C port.

1. [Detailed Manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-u2720q-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf)
2. [Tech Specs](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/ultrasharp-27-4k-usb-c-monitor-u2720q/apd/210-avjv/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section)

   I thought that since both the ends are USB-C compatible, I should be able to just connect them via USB-C cable and the IPAD display will be mirrored on the Display.
   However, I see that after the above step, Ipad starts charging, but the Monitor shows "No Input Display detected in USB-C".

Could someone advise what could be the issue.
Note: The usb-C cable I used is the one that was shipped by Apple along with IPad.

Comment: I'm not sure the cable shipped with the iPad supports a video signal. Did the monitor come with a USB-C cable or do you have another USB-C cable you can try?

Comment: Thanks.  I need to buy a new cable to try.  Hence wanted to check before buying.

Comment: Thanks @KevinGrabher you are correct.  There was a cable provided along with monitor and that worked.  Hence as you mentioned the cable with iPad most likely does not support it.